# Create table inside a Dropdown or RedCombobox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

how to load a table inside a dropdown list in asp.net? I need to fetch data from database. Please click the image for better understanding.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7iAk.png)

Comment: Do you want to load data from table to your drop-down or something else can you clear this point?

Comment: Yes..i want the data to load from database table

Comment: My suggestion is show any relevant column in the dropdown and on select show all other columns in a grid below

Comment: Hey man, I think you should use a modal popup on button click. it will full-fill your requirement.